# Is there a command line for Google Hangouts?

Tags: command-line, google-hangouts

I'm wanting to use a command line interface for Google hangouts, instead of having the Chrome extension. Is there anything about?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, there is a `github repo` for this by *tdryer* written in python called Hangups.

Installation is via `pip3`:

1. Update first:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Install `pip3` if absent:

   ```
   sudo apt install python-pip
   ```
3. Install `hangups`:

   ```
   pip3 install hangups
   ```

Information:

[Usage](https://hangups.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#python-package-index-pypi)

[Github Repo](https://github.com/tdryer/hangups)

Comment: Spent a fair amount of time installing this, and after doing so it appears that this is designed to be a terminal-based interactive interface, with no command line options to send messages. Am I missing something?

Comment: To send hangouts messages from the command line, use a script [like this one] after installing Hangups as above. (https://gist.github.com/tdryer/0cf6903eeb3dc948bae0).